# With Django CKeditor, how to load different toolbars on different fields?

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I'm using the django CKeditor plugin. My config is as follows:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
    'skin': 'moono', #'office2013'
    'toolbar': 'Custom', #selects from below
    'toolbar_Custom': [
          ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript']
    ],
'toolbar_simple': {
    'skin': 'moono',
    'toolbar': 'Custom',
    'toolbar_Custom': [
         ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'],
         ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],
    ],
},
'toolbar_basic':  {
    'toolbar': 'Basic'
},
'toolbar_full': {
    'toolbar': 'full',
},
}
```

I need to sometimes show the simple toolbar and sometimes the full one. How can I do this?

I hope there's an option like:

```
directions_car = RichTextField("Directions by car", max_length=1000, blank=False, default="", uses="toolbar_Custom")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `config_name` attribute to set the different toolbars.

```
directions_car = RichTextField("Directions by car", max_length=1000, blank=False, default="", config_name="toolbar_Custom")
```

[Reference](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor#optional-customizing-ckeditor-editor)

Comment: Perfect thank you. I hope this will also work with forms, so I can define a different toolbar for admins and for the front-end.